# Remainder of $\frac{P(X)}{X^2-1}$

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

> Given that P(X) a polynomial of degree at least $2$, that
>   $\frac{P(X)}{X-1}=q_1(X)$ with a remainder of $3$, that
>   $\frac{P(X)}{X+1}=q_2(X)$ with a remainder of $-5$, what is the remainder when $P(X)$ is divided by $X^2-1$?

**What I have done:**

$P(X)=q_1(X)*(x-1)+3$

$P(X)=q_2(X)*(x+1)-5$

$P(1)=3=2q_2(1)-5$ which gives $q_2(1)=4$

$P(-1)=-5=-2q_1(-1)+3$ which gives $q_1(-1)=4$

And that's about it. I'm not sure how I should approach this kind of exercise, can I have some hints on how to get it done?

Comment: Hint: Use the extended Euclidean algorithm to write $1 = a(x-1)+b(x+1)$. If you know how to solve such problems for integers (e.g. we know $n \mod 2$ and $n \mod 3$, what is $n \mod 6$), then you should know what to do here.

Comment: Note that $q_1$ and $q_2$ are also polynomials, so evaluating $P(1)$ and $P(-1)$ only gives you $q_2(1) = 4$ and $q_1(1) = 4$.

Comment: Could this problem be solved without the extended Euclidean Algorithm? I'm not really familiar with it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $P(x)=(x^2-1)Q(x)+ax+b$ for some numbers $a$ and $b$, and from $P(1)=3$ and $P(-1)=-5$, you can solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: This makes it so simple, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcr} P(x) &\equiv& 3\pmod{x-1}\\ P(x) &\equiv& -5\pmod{x+1}\end{array}\right.$$
imply that $-1$ is a root of $P(x)+5$ and $1$ is a root of $P(x)-3$. By imposing the first constraint
$$ P(x) = -5+(x+1)\,f(x) $$
and by imposing the second constraint $-8+(1+1)\,f(1) = 0$, or $f(1)=4$, from which
$$ P(x) = -5+(x+1)\left[4+(x-1)\,g(x)\right] =\color{red}{4x-1}+(x^2-1)g(x).$$
You may notice a strong similarity with one of the usual proofs of the Chinese remainder theorem: well, this is not a coincidence. And the given problem can be read as an interpolation problem, too: which linear polynomials equal $3$ at $x=1$ and $-5$ at $x=-1$? Just $4x-1$, clearly, it is enough to draw a line through $(1,3)$ and $(-1,-5)$.

Comment: How did you get $f(x)=4+(x-1)g(x)$?

Comment: @Alexander: that is the algebraic transcription of *f(1)=4*.